# IIS Session Problem

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I've got a Windows 2003 server and IIS 6.0 installed on it. And I publish only one web site on this server.

I got a problem with session such as:

When openning the page address with www or without www at the start (www.xyz.com or xyz.com), it keeps different sessions. Application is only one and same, and I want to only one session.

How could I set this?

Thanks,

Burak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Canonical URLs And 301 Redirects In Windows IIS 6

http://www.barrywise.com/2008/10/seo-canonical-urls-and-301-redirects-in-windows-iis-6-iis-7/

http://www.hpseo.co.uk/301-redirect-tutorial-iis/

Answer (score 1):

You are probably storing session information in cookies in the client's browser. Therefore, the browser sees www.xyz.com and xyz.com as two different website domains and creates two separate cookies.
To solve your problem you need to make sure your client always ends up on only one of the two domains. A couple of solutions are

- url rewriting in IIS
- 301 redirection

Personally I think the 301 redirection is the easiest/cleanest to implement.